# if else condition with and operator

Tags: c, if-statement, output, operators

```
void main()
{
int i=4,j=12;
if(i=5 && j>5)
    printf("Hi!");
else
        printf("Hello!");
}
```

First of all,the output of the above code is Hi!.Acording to me it should show a syntax error as i=5 is an assingment operator not i==5,if i==5 then also it is false and should print Hello,but how could it print Hi?

Comment: `!!(i = 5) == true` that's why.

Comment: Why do you ignore compiler warnings? If your compiler does not warn, instantly get a modern compiler! And as you say: "`=` is an assignment **operator**"

Answer (score 5):

The condition in the if statement

```
if(i=5 && j>5)
```

is equivalent to

```
if( i = ( 5 && j>5 ))
```

As 5 is not equal to 0 and j is indeed greater than 5 then the expression `( 5 && j>5 )` evaluates to `1` and is assigned to the variable `i`.

From the C Standard (6.5.16 Assignment operators)

> 3 An assignment operator stores a value in the object designated by
>   the left operand. **An assignment expression has the value of the left
>   operand after the assignment**...

So as the value of the variable `i` is equal to `1` then the if condition is executed.

It seems you mean

```
if(i==5 && j>5)
   ^^^^
```

Take into account that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Comment: Good for pointing out what may be an unexpected value assigned to `i`.

Answer (score 0):

`i=5` is a perfectly valid expression to put in a conditional, even if it's not a test for equality. That assignment produces a value that isn't zero, so the condition is still true.

Comment: @EugeneSh. some compilers will. There's no guarantee though.

Comment: Note that due to operator precedence, `i = 5` is not evaluated in OP code; rather the result of `5 && j>5` is assigned to `i`.

Comment: @DavidBowling Agreed, but either way, the point is - an assignment in an `if()` statement is valid C.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign variables in condition parameters like

```
While((a=b)!=null){
    ...
)
```

Try to output every variable (i,j) to see whats going on